# Integral and Limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a difference between integrating a function $f(x)$ between the limits $0<x<1$ and $0\leq x\leq1$? Do we write both as $\int_0^1f(x)dx$?

Answer (score 0):

The first case, you can write it as $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f(x)dx$, and evaluate this integral. Then take the limit $a \to 0^{+}, b \to 1^{-}$. For the latter no correction required as it implies that $0 \le x \le 1$.